# Реализация "плавающего" div'а при скроллинге страницы средствами только CSS?

Tags: css

Есть контент страницы, его много, а вот как сделать, и возможно ли выполнить только на CSS?Чтобы один блок позиционировался всегда, ну, скажем, по центру экрана, даже когда прокручиваешь страницу вниз, в сторону.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
div.myclass{
  position: fixed;
  left: 200px;
  top: 150px;    
}
```

Проблема в том, что он плавающим не будет. Он просто будет висеть на одном месте относительно окна браузера(адресной строки и прочего), а не относительно страницы.
По этому принципу любят баннеры делать. =/
А вот чтобы он красиво спускался с замедлением - только javascript/flash/silverlight

P.S. С центром -

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -250px; /*половина ширины дива*/
top: 50%;
margin-top: -135px; /*половина высоты дива*/
```